# $20$ different balloons numbered from $1$ to $20$, randomly split the balloons to pairs, when the order is not important, what’s the probability…

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $20$ different balloons numbered from $1$ to $20$.

A. If I randomly split the balloons to pairs, when the order is not important,

1. What is the probability that in each pair there will be an even balloon ($2,4,6$ etc)
2. What is the probability that in exactly $2$ pairs of balloons there won't be an even balloon.

B. Out of the $20$ balloons we choose $2$ balloons for each of four different kids. ($8$ balloons in total). What is the probability that each kid (out of $4$) will get at least $1$ even balloon?

I tried solving B - I tried to calculate the total number of options I have to choose $8$ balloons but I don't know if I'm correct - it's ${20 \choose 2 }{ 18\choose 2}  {16\choose 2}  {14\choose 2}$. I defined Ai as the event where the i'th kid gets at least one even balloon but I don't know how to proceed...

Thanks!

Comment: Is the fact that the things you're working with are, specifically, _balloons_, really so important for this question that it should be the only information you provide in the title of your questions to let readers decide whether they're interested in answering it?

Comment: I just couldn't find a proper title so I chose the obvious one

Comment: What is "obvious" about a title that **tells the reader exactly nothing about the character of your question**?

Comment: @Henning: I totally disagree. The title gave me a pretty good idea of the kind of question this was.

Comment: For the second part I am getting $\approx 0.4365$. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (A), you may think at a recursive solution. With 2 balloons, probability is 1. With four balloons, after you choose the first you have probability 2/3 to choose the second with opposite parity, and if you manage to do it you'll reduce to the case of 2 balloons. With six balloons you have 3/5 to choose the second one with parity opposite to the first, and if you manage to do it you'll reduce to the case of 4 balloons. Do the math :-)